# Retrieving event types over a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to retrieve some event types over a range of dates from one of our databases using **SQL Server Management studio**.

E.g.

```
104 Card printed    14/11/2015
205 Broken Attract Loop 15/11/2015
 56 Card printed    15/11/2015
245 Broken Attract Loop 16/11/2015
```

I'm trying to get to the dates for from 26/01 to 29/02 2016.

I've asked a colleague who was maintaining the database, who has sent me this:

```
Select 
    count(e.eventstart),    
    convert(e.eventstart),      
    et.eventtype
From 
    tblevents e, tbleventtype et
Where 
    et.eventypeid = e.eventtypeid
    And et.eventtype in ('field1','field2')
Group by 
    convert (e.eventstart), et.eventtype
```

And something about separating out time and date as `eventstart` is recorded as follows: 2009-01-17 16:48:58.000.

I can't make head nor tail of it; I'm a complete SQL novice, and no more help seems to be forthcoming from the ex-database maintainer.

Could some one please advise?

Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thanks @marc_s any ideas on separating the date from time?

Comment: I would just use a `WHERE (datecol) >= '20160126' AND (datecol) < '20160301'` - use the `>= .... < .....` notation, use the `<` against the "next day", and use the ISO-8601 format `YYYYMMDD` to be safe with any possible language/regional setting in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, you would simply convert to date:

```
Select count(e.eventstart), convert(date, e.eventstart),      
       et.eventtype
From tblevents e Join
     tbleventtype et
     on et.eventypeid = e.eventtypeid
Where et.eventtype in ('field1','field2')
Group by convert(date, e.eventstart), et.eventtype
Order by convert(date, e.eventstart), et.eventtype;
```

You should inform your colleague that explicit `JOIN`s are the right way to code SQL.  This syntax is more powerful and expressive than using commas in the `FROM` clause to (conceptually) create Cartesian product that is then filtered using the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff , That seems to have done it, query running now. Will let you know if I have any issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
    count(e.eventstart),    
    cast(e.eventstart as date) [eventstart],      
    et.eventtype
From 
    tblevents e, tbleventtype et
Where 
    et.eventypeid = e.eventtypeid
    And et.eventtype in ('field1','field2')
    And cast(e.eventstart as date) between '2016-01-26' and '2016-02-29'
Group by 
    cast(e.eventstart as date), et.eventtype
```

Comment: Thanks Every one, this is all sorted, consider closed. @Andrey Morozov